# How to redirect on same page using javasript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to Create a website and in which there is a button and i have gave it a link to redirect on same page like :-

```
<button><a href="#explore">Explore</a></button>
<div id="explore">

</div>
```

When i am opening or refreshing the page, without clicking on button it redirects me to #explore div but i want it to redirect on a click.

So please help me to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete an anchor from an  tag and put the functionality instead to a JS. For example:

```
<button id="buttonAnchor">Explore</button>
<div id="explore">

</div>
<script>
   let btn = getElementById('buttonAnchor');
   btn.onclick = function() {
      explore = getElementById('explore');
      window.scrollTp(0, explore.offsetTop;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, i have done more resarch on it and find a easier way <input type='button'value='Explore Now' id="btn" class="animated infinite bounce" onclick="document.location.href='#explore';"/>

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code like...

**Method-1**

```
<button><a href="">Explore</a></button>
<div id="explore">

</div>
```

**Method-2**

```
<button><a href="#" id="myLink">Explore</a></button>
<script>
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    window.location.reload();
});
</script>
```